# Compare input data with another Table

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Sign Up option in the app I'm developing and to validate who can register I created another Table with the name ORDER.

This table Order have two fields (name and number).

Sign Up is connected to the table USERS and I want to compare the name and number inserted on the Sign Up to the data inserted in table ORDER.

For example:

Sign UP
Username: test
Password: test
Name: User Test
Number: 12345

ORDER:
Name: User Test
Number: 12345

It can only register the sign up info in the table USER if the Name and Number are in the table ORDER.

Can you help me?

```
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference Users, Order;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    Users = database.getReference("Users");
    Order = database.getReference("Order");

    edtUser =(MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.edtUserName);
    edtPassword =(MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

    btnSignIn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    btnSignUp= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_up);

    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showSignUpDiaolog();

        }
    });
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signIn(edtUser.getText().toString(),edtPassword.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}


private void signIn(final String user, final String pwd) {
    Users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.child(user).exists())
            {
                if(!user.isEmpty())
                {
                    User login = dataSnapshot.child(user).getValue(User.class);
                    if (login.getPassword().equals(pwd))
                    {
                        Intent homeActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Home.class);
                        Common.currentUser = login;
                        startActivity(homeActivity);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password errada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }}
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Introduza o utilizador!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Utilizador não existe!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void showSignUpDiaolog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Criação da conta:");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Preencher todos os campos!");

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View sign_up_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sign_up_layout,null);

    edtNewUser = (MaterialEditText)sign_up_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtNewUserName);
    edtNewPassword = (MaterialEditText)sign_up_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtNewPassword);
    edtNewOrdem = (MaterialEditText)sign_up_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtNewOrdem);
    edtNewName = (MaterialEditText)sign_up_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtNewName);


    alertDialog.setView(sign_up_layout);
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_24dp);
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();

        }
    });
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            final User user = new User (
                    edtNewUser.getText().toString(),
                    edtNewPassword.getText().toString(),
                    edtNewOrdem.getText().toString(),
                    edtNewName.getText().toString());


                Users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    String passwordvalid = edtNewPassword.getText().toString();
                    String usernamevalid = edtNewUser.getText().toString();


                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(passwordvalid))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password não definida.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(usernamevalid))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Utilizador não definido.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    if (passwordvalid.length() < 8)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password tem que conter no mínimo 8 caracteres.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    if(dataSnapshot.child(user.getUserName()).exists())
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Utilizador já registado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else
                    {
                        Users.child(user.getUserName())
                                .setValue(user);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registo efetuado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
            dialogInterface.dismiss();

        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this you should set the column *username* as a *unique_key* and not create another table.

For example, in *PostgreSQL* if you want to create your table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL,
    username varchar UNIQUE,
    password varchar,
    name varchar,
    test_number integer
);
```

The `UNIQUE` contraint will reject any row creation with an existing *username*.
For other *RDBMS* the syntax will be slightly different but almost the same.

#### Add ID on your tables

You should always have an `id` for each table because of efficiency and structure issues. An ID will make rows unique independently of other properties, it will also provide a faster way to make JOIN queries. An ID it's data-independent and you won't need to worry on finding a row by a field that may or may not have changed.

Answer (score 0):

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ1HL.png)

As you can see I want to check if the userName and name are registed on Order Table. If they're not they can't register on the table Users. If they're the info is recorded on Users Table and create the account.

I've a list of people that can register on the app and I want to control with those two fields.